# Trying to connect to an access with a UDL file

Tags: ms-access, ado.net, jet, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to connect to an Access database via a UDL file.  I'm wanting to generate a connection string so that I can connect to an access database via ADO.NET.  It's been a few years since I've tried to do this.

I have Visual Studio 2015 Pro and Microsoft Access 2016 installed on my Windows 10 x64 pro machine.  When I create a .udl file I have the following available options:

- Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
- Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Search
- Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
- Microsoft OLE DB Simple Provider
- MSDataShape
- OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services
- SQL Server Native Client 11.0

I think that in years past I would also see Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB in this list.  From the research I've done I think that Jet 4.0 is deprecated and that I should be using the Access Database Engine.  I find the following versions that I think are that:

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

[Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358)

[Microsoft Access 2016 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50040)

I downloaded the x64 version of Microsoft Access 2016 Runtime and when I try to install it I get the following error:

*We can’t install the 64-bit version of Office because we found the following 32-bit programs on your PC:
Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component
Please uninstall all 32-bit Office programs, then retry installing 64-bit Office.  If you want to install 32-bit Office instead, please run the 32-bit setup.*

I've tried the 32-bit version of the Microsoft Access 2016 Runtime and I get the same message:

*We can’t install the 32-bit version of Office because we found the following 64-bit programs on your PC:
Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component 64-bit Registration
Please uninstall all 64-bit Office programs, then retry installing 32-bit Office.  If you want to install 64-bit Office instead, please run the 64-bit setup.*

I've tried closing all open Microsoft Office and Visual Studio applications and I get the same error.  Am I installing the right component?  Any way to get it to install correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably miss the *ACE* driver listed here - and only this, not the runtimes:

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: Dumb question: Why is it called the ACE and not the ADE?

Comment: Good question. Could be from _ACcess database Engine_ or that the C refers to _Core_. But I have no clue.